Snowflake - Dynamic tables recommendation
We have a use case in which we have 3 final transactional standard tables that are loaded each day with new data of a certain process day, the common use case is current date -1 of the on premise databases.
We are exploring on dynamic tables to create one on which this 3 tables are joined (using left joins - tab1 left join tab 2 left join tab3) but the specific requirement is that the final dynamic table should only refresh when the current date - 1 data is already loaded on the 3 previous standard tables.
So if in tab1 the new data is loaded, the dynamic table shouldn't refresh until the data from the same day is loaded into the other 2 tables previously.
Do u guys have any idea on how to accomplish this? I don't understand if declaring the final dynamic table on DOWNSTREAM lag should be useful or we will need another type of validation (such as a cte on the dynamic table that joins the tables with inner join, then filters each table with only the data that's in the 3 tables and then do the left joins or something like that)
Any thoughts?

DOWNSTREAM is only useful if the 3 tables that build the final dynamic table are also dynamic tables, which I don't think relates to your case.

How do you current orchestrate the loading of the 3 tables?  You could add a step at the end of that orchestration that executes a ALTER DYNAMIC TABLE REFRESH command, which would confirm that the previous 3 tables have been refreshed.  But, not sure how you control that process now.

Hi @MikeWalton, currently we have a separate transient table that register each load on the 3 tables as a flag with 0 or 1. We have one stream over each of this final tables that make CDC over this tables and a task running every 2 hs asking if the streams have data, if one of this streams does have data, we group by the data by this process day and ask to this "status" table if every row for that particular day is on this flag column is 1, if all are 1, then the final table makes the left joins, etc. So what i'm looking is something hopefully more simple

@MikeWalton that ALTER DYNAMIC TABLE REFRESH command executes an incremental or full refresh? or that depends on how u define the dynamic table? The final table needs lefts joins, and an union all, at least one of them

It will refresh the table based on whether it's incremental or full.  I'd recommend creating the dynamic table with AUTO and then do a SHOW DYNAMIC TABLES command to see what Snowflake has determined the refresh to be.

@MikeWalton hi Mike, i put as u recommend this ALTER DYNAMIC TABLE REFRESH inside a task that is the one that valides all the requirements we have. But the problem seems to be that the ALTER DYNAMIC TABLE REFRESH can't be called from inside a task maybe? Because i execute the task and the refresh is not starting as if i manually execute the same line of code, it does. Do u know if theres a limitation there? thanks
